# Typescript Using Paths To Reference Typings In Different Folder Than File Path

Tags: typescript

I have a situation where the path to a library file is different from where the typings file is located for that library. Specifically I have the library file in one folder but I'm trying to use the typings from the @types folder in node modules. I'm wondering if I can use the paths property in tsconfig to handle this problem.

Example:
src/app.ts

```
import Chart from './lib/Chart.min.js'; // <-- Says it cannot find module
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "amd",
        "target": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "outDir": "./FileCabinet/SuiteScripts/PowerTrends",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "lib": [
          "es5",
          "es2015",
          "dom",
          "es2017"
        ],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
           "./lib/Chart.min.js": ["node_modules/@types/chart.js"] // <-- This doesn't seem to work
        }
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: You don't need to provide path aliases in typescript config for @types under the `node_modules` directory. Just delete the paths prop from your tsconfig and it should be fine imported as `import x from 'chart'` or something similar

Comment: The problem here is that in the compiled file the path has to be `../lib/Chart.min.js` exactly. If I remove the `../lib/` in the .ts file then it also goes away in the compiled file.